# Can I create a Control Object?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to create a like object entity, like having 3 buttons with the same code (events, methods and code in general). But making a same entity, like just one object.

Comment: Not clear if you are talking about a UserControl or just three buttons that share the same event handlers.

Comment: 3 Controls forming one entity

Comment: You would have to find a better way to describe what an "entity" is.  That's the unclear part.  My guess would be, put three buttons on a UserControl.

Comment: Like a object un oriented object programing